# N: Ignoring file 'google.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, sudo, apt-get

I have tried to install google-chrome and it was finished, then I ran `sudo apt-get update` command and it is showing this error [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro5Aa.png).
How to solved it?

Answer (score 2):

To solve:
 1. `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d`
 2. `sudo mv google.listsudo google.list`
 3. `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: This answer is useful and I able to solved. Thank you